# Displaying Info about a JSON User

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

Create a jQuery event handler that will initiate an Ajax request, retrieve the data, and extract the information needed. I need to display the users name and email based off their entered username in a `<div id="results">`. It also needs to say in `<div id="results">` that it couldn't find the user if no username was found based on the input.

This if the user JSON file I'm accessing https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
    var username = $("#user").val();
    $.ajax( {
        url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/',
        method: 'GET'
    }).then(function(data) {
        $.get(username);
        $.each(data, function(index, user) {
            if (user['username'] == username) {
                $('#results').text(''+ user.name +' ('+user.email +')');
            } else {
                $('#results').text('Sorry, no user could be found with the username '+ username+ '');
            }


        });

    });
}); 
});
</script>
```

I am able to find the users based on username but I can't figure out what my next step would be to get that usernames name and email.

Comment: `$.get()` is used to make AJAX requests. It's unlikely you want to use it here

Comment: You want something like this... `if (user.username === username) { $('#results').text(\`${user.name} <${user.email}>\`) }`

Comment: $('#results').text(`${user.name} <${user.email}>`) Incorprating that doesn't show the name or email of the specified username. It just outputs <${user.name}> <${user.email}>

Comment: That's quite literally impossible. Please [update the code in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55554600/edit) with what you have now

Comment: Phil not to bother you again but I have finally got my code working. The only problem I am having now is that everything is defaulting to the else statement but if I remove it, and enter a known username the if statement will run. If it is an unknown username nothing happens. But with the else statement included in my code known and unknown usernames will run in the else statement. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need $.get(), and just use a JS loop. This snippet works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
        var username = $("#user").val();
        $.ajax( {
            url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/',
            method: 'GET'
        }).success(function(data) {

            // Data is an array, let loop through each, to get object data
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                // Get object's property values
                var dataUsername = data[i].username;
                var dataUserEmail = data[i].email;

                // Output user data if user is matched
                if(dataUsername.toLowerCase() == username.toLowerCase()){
                    $('#results').text(dataUsername + ' ' + dataUserEmail);
                }
            }
        });
    }); 
});
```